# SQL query execution using panda library

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have an SQL query like this "select (ShipMode),(count(OrderID)*100/8994) as Score from friends.sampledatapanda(I have a CSV file, so ignore this)
group by 1". Which I want to execute the same using panda library on Jupyter.
Please help.

Comment: Are you saying you have a .csv file which you want to read with pandas and replicate your SQL query, or you want to execute the SQL query against your database using pandas?

Comment: Hey Ben! I have CSV file on which I have to perform this SQL query. I have read the file using pandas and now I have to execute this query which I mentioned.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the .csv file and the output you are expecting?

Comment: Ben, You can view my csv and download it from here. I am performing operations on the same csv file. The link is https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236
And the output I am expecting is 
Ship mode, OrderID
First Class 1538
Same Day 543
Second Class 1945
Standard Class 5968

Comment: Thanks. Are you just looking for a record count by ship mode?

Comment: I want the percentages of the OrderID with respect to the unique ship mode. Count of orderID in percentage. Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas' `value_counts()` method to count the number of values, and use the `normalize=True` parameter to get the frequencies. Assuming you have read your data into a DataFrame called `df`:

```
df['Ship Mode'].value_counts(normalize=True)

Out[3]:

Standard Class    0.597158
Second Class      0.194617
First Class       0.153892
Same Day          0.054333
Name: Ship Mode, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ben, you are damn correct!
but one quick question but what if I want the values with respect to only Order ID? Since the results in MySQL were quite different from the current results. I will show you the results of MySQL query if you want.
Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: If you could show me the results from your MySQL query that would be great, then I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Standard Class,0.6636
Second Class,0.2163
Same Day,0.0604
First Class,0.1710
The first column is for the ship mode and the second one is the count of order id divided by total number of rows in CSV which is 8994(to find out the percentage)

Comment: The data file I downloaded from the link in your comment contains 9,994 rows. The normalize=True parameter is finding the count and dividing by the number of non-NaN rows (of which there are none). Can you check the number of records in your DataFrame?

Comment: Ben, My Mistake or My bad.
The problem is solved now.
Thanks a lot.It works now. :)